# Odoo (OpenERP) Lockout Mechanism

Tags: captcha, odoo, lockout

How can i prevent the user from logging in odoo (openerp) system after 5 attempts of invalid username or password.

I have found a workaround to my question to have a captcha ( https://apps.openerp.com/apps/modules/7.0/web_captcha/) installed on my system but i don't need a captcha any more.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your question i tried to create a simple module using which you can restrict the Odoo users not to login for some time.

Based on Configuration, it will unlock the users. Write back to me if you find any Bugs in it. You can clone it from git@github.com:muralikrishnareddy/lockout.git . or its location is https://github.com/muralikrishnareddy/lockout Its for odoo-8.0.